# Clean camera transitions

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, camera

I'm trying to have cameras cut to the next animation clean but it doesn't work. I animated the camera movement and rotation so these animations deal with the camera.

1st example:
When you have two keyframes precisely next to each other(frame to frame, back to back), shouldn't it cut directly to the next keyframe without anything in between? That's not what it does. You can see for a split second the rotation and movement, so it looks weird. How do I work around this? I tried messing with the right click settings, setting it to broken, etc., but none of it worked.

2nd example:
When I play a new animation clip, it does the same thing as described above. Instead of transitioning like a normal camera cut, you can see for a brief moment the activity between the transitions. It looks really messy. How do I work around this?

Thanks

Comment: sounds like a job for cinecamera